# Probability of $3$ students tossing a coin $10$ times

Tags: probability

> A class has three (3) students. Each student tosses a coin $10$ times. Find the chance that at least one of the students gets exactly $5$ heads.

The probability of getting $5$ heads in $10$ tosses $= \binom{10}{5} (1/2)^5 (1/2)^5 = 252/1024 = 0.2461$. Similarly the probability of not getting five heads $=1-0.2461=0.7539$.

The probability of three students not getting $5$ heads $=(0.7539)^3=0.4285$.

So at last the probability of at least one student get exactly five heads $=1-0.4285$ which is $0.5715$. It's correct!

Comment: Your calculation seems to be correct. Perhaps you are expected to give an exact answer, or suffering from errors resulting from successive rounding?

Comment: How do you know that the answer you got is wrong?

Comment: Thanks Gerry Myerson I corrected myself!

Answer (score 1):

*This is a copy of my comment, just posted so that the question doesn't keep coming up because it has no answers.*

---

Your calculation seems to be correct. Perhaps you are expected to give an exact answer, or suffering from errors resulting from successive rounding?